Is it possible to use math with semiverbatim?
I have this MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
%   arc=0pt,
%   outer arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
}

\newcommand{\Proc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\Blue}[1]{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Com}[1]{\textcolor{comcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\ensuremath{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}}
\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}
\definecolor{comcolor}{RGB}{10,161,119}
\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[text width=4.5cm, colback=blue!5!white]
    \begin{semiverbatim}
    \Proc{Majority}(\Blue{$a_i$})
    Repeat for each \Var{$a_i$}
      if \Var{c} == 0
            \Var{\alpha} = \Var{$a_i$}
            \Var{c} = 1 
      elif \Var{$a_i$} == \Var{\alpha}
            \Var{c} = \Var{c} + 1
      else
            \Var{c} = \Var{c} - 1
    \end{semiverbatim}
        \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}


I would like the a_i to render as math. Can that be done in semiverbatim?


\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
%   arc=0pt,
%   outer arc=0pt,
    colback=white,
}

\newcommand{\Proc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\Blue}[1]{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Com}[1]{\textcolor{comcolor}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\ensuremath{\textcolor{varcolor}{#1}}}
\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}
\definecolor{comcolor}{RGB}{10,161,119}
\definecolor{varcolor}{RGB}{15,122,183}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[text width=4.5cm, colback=blue!5!white]
    \begin{semiverbatim}
    \Proc{Majority}(\Blue{\(a\sb{i}\)})
    Repeat for each \Var{a\sb{i}}
      if \Var{c} == 0
            \Var{\alpha} = \Var{a\sb{i}}
            \Var{c} = 1 
      elif \Var{a\sb{i}} == \Var{\alpha}
            \Var{c} = \Var{c} + 1
      else
            \Var{c} = \Var{c} - 1
    \end{semiverbatim}
        \end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}

delete $ from \Var as that is already math, then use \sb for subscripts.

Thank you very much.
